# Python list comprehension to create list of pairs, two at a time

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I am trying to generate a list of pairs using a comprehension, that creates the pairs two at a time. I can create a list of lists, where each sub-list is two pairs, e.g.,:

```py
mylist = [[(f'2i_{i}',2*i),(f'8i_{i}',8*i)] for i in range(1,4)]

# [[('2i_1', 2), ('8i_1', 8)], [('2i_2', 4), ('8i_2', 16)], [('2i_3', 6), ('8i_3', 24)]]
```

or a list of pairs of pairs, e.g.,:

```py
mylist = [((f'2i_{i}',2*i),(f'8i_{i}',8*i)) for i in range(1,4)]

# [(('2i_1', 2), ('8i_1', 8)), (('2i_2', 4), ('8i_2', 16)), (('2i_3', 6), ('8i_3', 24))]
```

but what I want it to look like is:

```py
# [('2i_1', 2), ('8i_1', 8), ('2i_2', 4), ('8i_2', 16), ('2i_3', 6), ('8i_3', 24)]
```

Is there a simple way of using a comprehension to create a list like this?

Comment: `[j for i in range(1,4) for j in [(f'2i_{i}',2*i),(f'8i_{i}',8*i)]]`. See the linked duplicate for an explanation.

Comment: `mylist = [(f'{j}i_{i}',j*i) for i in range(1,4) for j in (2, 8)]`